# How does this expression work? "require('dotenv').config();"

Tags: node.js, import, syntax, config, dotenv

I saw this expression:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

At the beginning of a `server.js` file within a NodeJS project. I am just curious to know how does it work and what does it do?

Because almost always I have seen a variable before the `require` expression line like

```
 const express = require('express');
```

and afterwards it will be used somehow like

```
const app = express();
```

But `require('dotenv').config();` looks different and it hasn't been used like the common approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Import Types

> When you define a `type` in the package.json file, it will set that import type for the whole project. `require()` cannot be used in type `module` and `import` cannot be used in type `commonJS`

**Example package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "stack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "type": /* either commonJS or module */
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

after setting the import type here are the examples of both types in action

```js
// if "type": "commonJS"
const package = require('package')

// if "type": "module"
import package from 'package'
```

#### 'dotenv'

This is the environment variables module to read `.env` files. Below are the two ways to import it whether you're using type `commonJS` or `module`

```js
require('dotenv').config() // commonJS

import {} from 'dotenv/config' // module
```

works like this...

**.env** file

```
TOKEN=THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN
```

then in a `.js` file

```js
/* after importing 'dotenv' one of the two ways listed above */

console.log(process.env.TOKEN) // outputs "THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN"
```

#### 'express'

this is the two ways to import express with either `commonJS` or `module`

```js
const express = require('express') // commonJS

import express from 'express' // module

const app = express() // initializes express app
```

##### [CommonJS vs ES Module](https://blog.logrocket.com/commonjs-vs-es-modules-node-js/#:%7E:text=ES%20modules%20are%20the%20standard,encapsulating%20JavaScript%20code%20for%20reuse.)

> ES modules are the standard for JavaScript, while CommonJS is the default in Node. js. The ES module format was created to standardize the JavaScript module system. It has become the standard format for encapsulating JavaScript code for reuse.

Comment: So you say we can also use `import{}` statement instead of `require()` statement in the JavaScript like what we do in the TypeScript?

Comment: If so, why all JS code I have seen used `require()` and I have never seen a JS code that uses `import` statement?

Comment: in `package.json`... the type value can either be `commonJS` or `module`, this will set the import type throughout the whole project.

Comment: would u like me to edit an example into my answer?

Comment: I appreciate it.

Comment: i edited my answer and explained types at the top

Comment: Thank you again. So you say when we put `require('dotenv').config()` in our code, it means it reads the `.env` file and initializes all variables imported from there in that file.

Comment: yes that is correct.